# Power Query Looping

Tags: loops, powerquery

I used Power Query to pull all of the unique Item Types tested in the past month:

```
let
  Source = Sql.Database("XXX", "YYY"),
  dbo_tblTest = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="tblTest"]}[Data],
  #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(dbo_tblTest, each Date.IsInPreviousNMonths([Test_Stop], 1)),
  #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Custom", each Text.Start([Item],5)),
  #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Added Custom", {"Custom"})
in
  #"Removed Duplicates"
```

To get:

> 1. Test_ID --- Item --- Test_Start --- Test_Stop --- Custom
> 2. 2585048 --- B1846-6-02 --- 1/14/2014 12:46 --- 6/25/2015 14:28 --- B1846
> 3. 2589879 --- B1843-5-05 --- 12/23/2013 16:46 --- 6/25/2015 14:19 --- B1843
> 4. 2633483 --- B1907-1-04 --- 8/21/2014 20:47 --- 6/10/2015 6:20 --- B1907
> 5. 2638786 --- B1361-2-04 --- 6/13/2013 14:21 --- 6/16/2015 14:15 --- B1361
> 6. 2675663 --- B1345-2-02 --- 5/23/2014 18:39 --- 6/25/2015 21:27 --- B1345

Next, I want to use Power Query to pull the past 10 tests for each of the Item Types listed in Query1, regardless of time period. I figured out how to pull the past 10 tests for the Item Types separately, but not all together in one query.

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("XXX", "YYY"),
    dbo_tblTest = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="tblTest"]}[Data],
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(dbo_tblTest, each Text.StartsWith([Item], "B1846")),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Test_Stop", Order.Descending}}),
    #"Kept First Rows" = Table.FirstN(#"Sorted Rows",10)
in
    #"Kept First Rows"
```

To get:

> 1. Test_ID --- Item --- Test_Start --- Test_Stop --- Value
> 2. 11717643 --- B1846-6-02 --- 7/23/2015 12:48 --- 7/23/2015 12:57 --- 43725341
> 3. 11716432 --- B1846-1-21 --- 7/23/2015 10:23 --- 7/23/2015 10:29 --- 43724705
> 4. 11715802 --- B1846-1-21 --- 7/23/2015 9:28 --- 7/23/2015 10:29 --- 43724720
> 5. 11715505 --- B1846-1-21 --- 7/23/2015 8:59 --- 7/23/2015 9:06 --- 43724675
> 6. 11715424 --- B1846-1-21 --- 7/23/2015 8:36 --- 7/23/2015 8:59 --- 43724690
> 7. 11713680 --- B1846-1-55 --- 7/23/2015 5:50 --- 7/23/2015 6:07 --- 43725239
> 8. 11691169 --- B1846-6-04 --- 7/20/2015 22:47 --- 7/22/2015 20:18 --- 43642835
> 9. 11690466 --- B1846-6-04 --- 7/20/2015 21:30 --- 7/22/2015 18:41 --- 43642729
> 10. 11701183 --- B1846-1-140 --- 7/21/2015 21:34 --- 7/21/2015 22:24 --- 43667358
> 11. 11701184 --- B1846-6-04 --- 7/21/2013 20:35 --- 7/21/2015 20:46 --- 43667359

Is it possible to use Power Query to pull all needed data in one query? If not, is it possible to use VBA with Power Query to get it done?

Answer (score 5):

In Power Query if you're thinking about how to loop, you often find a higher-order library function that does just what you want. In this case, it's grouping.

Grouping splits up a table by some key, in your case the `Custom` column of the first table. You can rewrite your "keep past 10" logic into a function that you apply within each grouped table using `Table.TransformColumns`, then expand the grouped tables back out into one flat table.

Your query should be something like:

```
let
  Source = Sql.Database("XXX", "YYY"),
  dbo_tblTest = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="tblTest"]}[Data],
  #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(dbo_tblTest, "Custom", each Text.Start([Item],5)),
  #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"Custom"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table}}),
  Custom2 = Table.TransformColumns(#"Grouped Rows", {{"Grouped", (groupedTable) =>
      let
          #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(groupedTable,{{"Test_Stop", Order.Descending}}),
          #"Kept First Rows" = Table.FirstN(#"Sorted Rows",10)
      in
          #"Kept First Rows"}}),
  #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(Custom2,{"Grouped"}),
  #"Expanded Grouped" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Grouped", Table.ColumnNames(#"Added Custom"))
in
  #"Expanded Grouped"
```

Comment: I did find one problem. This only keeping the last 10 within the previous month. If the last 10 would be outside of the previous month filter, then it is not pulled.

Comment: With that filter removed and then doing a merge with my first query, I was able to get down to the last 10 tests for only the items tested in the previous month. It is very slow though, especially when I bump it up to the last 100 tests. Is this the best solution with Power Query?

Comment: It's possible that doing any database grouping operations over a text substring is going to be slow, sure. Can you change the data in the table so the grouping is on a whole column, not a substring?