# MS Power Query Looping

Tags: json, loops, powerquery

This is a different looping question from [Power Query Looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31620353/power-query-looping).

I'm using Power Query to pull data from api.automatic.com; specifically, a list of trips.  I'm able to pull the first set of information, but I can't figure out how to loop to get all information.

This is what I have so far:

```
let
    Source = Web.Contents("https://api.automatic.com/trip/",[Headers=[#"Authorization"="Bearer XXX"]]),
    #"Imported JSON" = Json.Document(Source),
    results = #"Imported JSON"[results],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(results, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"url", "id", "driver", "user", "started_at", "ended_at", "distance_m", "duration_s", "vehicle", "start_location", "start_address", "end_location", "end_address", "path", "fuel_cost_usd", "fuel_volume_l", "average_kmpl", "average_from_epa_kmpl", "score_events", "score_speeding", "hard_brakes", "hard_accels", "duration_over_70_s", "duration_over_75_s", "duration_over_80_s", "vehicle_events", "start_timezone", "end_timezone", "city_fraction", "highway_fraction", "night_driving_fraction", "idling_time_s", "tags"}, {"url", "id", "driver", "user", "started_at", "ended_at", "distance_m", "duration_s", "vehicle", "start_location", "start_address", "end_location", "end_address", "path", "fuel_cost_usd", "fuel_volume_l", "average_kmpl", "average_from_epa_kmpl", "score_events", "score_speeding", "hard_brakes", "hard_accels", "duration_over_70_s", "duration_over_75_s", "duration_over_80_s", "vehicle_events", "start_timezone", "end_timezone", "city_fraction", "highway_fraction", "night_driving_fraction", "idling_time_s", "tags"})
in
    #"Expanded Column1"
```

The JSON that is output returns a value under `_metadata.next` that's the URL to get the *next* set of data. How to I have the PQ grab that value, repull using that URL, and continue doing so until that `next` value is null or blank?

Comment: Have a look at List.Generate as the better performing recursive operation: http://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/06/25/using-list-generate-to-make-multiple-replacements-of-words-in-text-in-power-query/

Comment: `List.Generate` only helps when you know how many times you have to iterate the query; what about when the number of times is _not_ known?

Comment: That's not my understanding. Unfortunately the documentation is terrible, but the 2nd argument is a condition, so you could write sth like " each _<> null and _<> "" " and the iteration will stop as you've requested.

Comment: For the moment I'm just using PowerShell to do the pull to a `.json` file and then loading _that_ into Excel. A scheduled task to do the PowerShell script periodically and I should be fine.

Comment: Should be doable: https://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/how-to-schedule-a-powershell-script/

Comment: write a recursive function, is this question still active?

Answer (score 1):

Use [List.Generate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-generate) to pull the data until the next token is null.

> List.Generate(initial as function, condition as function, next as function, optional selector as nullable function) as list

Code with explanations *(untested as I can't access the API):*

```
let
    // Helper function to get results and next token.
    get = (url as any, headers as any) as record =>
        let
            source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url, headers)),
            results = try source[results] otherwise null,
            next = try source[_metadata][next] otherwise null,
            return = [results=results, next=next]
        in
            return,

    url = "https://api.automatic.com/trip/",
    headers = [Headers=[#"Authorization"="Bearer XXX"]],

    // Returns a list of lists of records.
    return = 
        List.Generate(
            // Initial value.
            ()=> get(url, headers),
            // If condition is true select (make a list) the result.
            each [results] <> null,
            // Generate the next list if condition is true.
            each get([next], headers),
            // Return (select) only [results].
            each [results])
in
    return
```

Understanding what the [each](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/understanding-power-query-m-functions) keyword does helps:

> The each keyword is used to easily create simple functions. “each ...” is syntactic sugar for a function signature that takes the parameter “() => ...”
>
> Each is useful when combined with the lookup operator, which is applied by default to For example,  `each [CustomerID]` is the same as `each _[CustomerID]`, which is the same as `(_) => _[CustomerID]`